# Animating widths in Framer Motion causes content to flash

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I am animating the widths of some columns with Framer Motion and it is causing the content inside of the last column to flash as it is animating.

Are there any approaches for avoiding this issue?

[CodeSandbox here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-flashing-h4mhgw?file=/src/App.js) You may need to refresh the sandbox a few times to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by setting the containing div to be `display: flex;`.

```
<div
  style={{
    position: "relative",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100vh",
    display: "flex"
  }}
>
  ...
</div>
```

[Codesandbox working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-flashing-forked-g56n3p?file=/src/App.js:229-1374)

I think the issue is specific to elements with `display: block` and `div` elements are `display: block` by default. I'm unsure why just the last element is flashing. I may do some more digging in my spare time if my curiosity gets the best of me.